# Beamer: matrix of TikZ nodes with one node having multiple lines

Tags: beamer, tikz-matrix

I am trying to construct a matrix with two columns and multiple rows. The top row has two nodes, both of which need to hold multiple lines of text and math. When I follow the prescribed method of using curly braces for the cell with multiple lines along with `\\`, I am simply not able to compile the code (texmaker runs forever, and my machine gets scarily hot, and I have to close the application). Any help would be much appreciated.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,overlay-beamer-styles}

%%%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%%%%%%%%
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}


\newtcbtheorem[]{mylemmma}{Lemma}{colframe=green,colback=white, width=\textwidth}{lem}
\tcbset{colframe=green, colback=white}  
\resetcounteronoverlays{tcb@cnt@mylemmma}

\begin{document}
\section{Proofs}
\newtcbtheorem[]{mydef}{Problem Statement}{colframe=white, colback=white}{ps}
\tcbset{colframe=black, colback=white}              

\resetcounteronoverlays{tcb@cnt@mydef}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[optimization problem/.style = {%
            rounded corners, 
            draw = blue,
            thick,
            fill= yellow,
            inner ysep=5pt,
            inner xsep=5pt,
            align = center},
            myplainproblem/.style = {%
            rounded corners, 
            draw = blue,
            thick,
            fill= white,
            inner ysep=5pt,
            inner xsep=5pt,
            align = center},
            ]

\matrix[matrix of nodes,row sep=1em,column sep=1em,
    nodes={anchor=west,optimization problem,
    visible on=<\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn+2*\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-2\relax->,},
     column 1/.style={nodes={myplainproblem,
     }},
     column 2/.style={nodes={myplainproblem,
     }}, 
     row 1/.style={nodes={optimization problem,
     }}, 
    ](M){
    vectors   &  matrices \\
    reason 1    & matrix reason 1\\
    reason 2    & matrix reason 2\\
};          

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The curly braces method requires to set a `text width`, say. (The `pgfmanual` is not too explicit about it, I know.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When one looks at the corresponding part of the pgfmanual v3.1.5 in section **60.2 End-of-Lines and End-of-Row Characters in Matrices of Nodes**, one finds that in the example the `text width` is set. It does mention

> This problem arises only when you use the text width option of nodes.

but I would agree that it is not clear that it implies that one has to set the `text width` for the curly braces trick to work. Anyway, once we set it, it does work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,overlay-beamer-styles}

%%%%%%%%%
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%%%%%%%%
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}


\newtcbtheorem[]{mylemmma}{Lemma}{colframe=green,colback=white, width=\textwidth}{lem}
\tcbset{colframe=green, colback=white}  
\resetcounteronoverlays{tcb@cnt@mylemmma}

\begin{document}
\section{Proofs}
\newtcbtheorem[]{mydef}{Problem Statement}{colframe=white, colback=white}{ps}
\tcbset{colframe=black, colback=white}              

\resetcounteronoverlays{tcb@cnt@mydef}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[optimization problem/.style = {%
            rounded corners, 
            draw = blue,
            thick,
            fill= yellow,
            inner ysep=5pt,
            inner xsep=5pt,
            align = center},
            myplainproblem/.style = {%
            rounded corners, 
            draw = blue,
            thick,
            fill= white,
            inner ysep=5pt,
            inner xsep=5pt,
            align = center},
            ]

\matrix[matrix of nodes,row sep=1em,column sep=1em,
    nodes={anchor=west,optimization problem,text width=8em,
    visible on=<\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn+2*\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-2\relax->,},
     column 1/.style={nodes={myplainproblem,
     }},
     column 2/.style={nodes={myplainproblem,
     }}, 
     row 1/.style={nodes={optimization problem,
     }}, 
    ](M){
    {vectors\\ tensors}   &  {matrices\\ tableaux} \\
    reason 1    & matrix reason 1\\
    reason 2    & matrix reason 2\\
};          

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you feel that the manual could be clearer here (I'd certainly agree with this statement), you can submit an [issue](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues).